# Configuration of Selenium 2 (WebDriver), using IE and upload file with WebDriver

Tags: java, internet-explorer, file-upload, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I configure Selenium WebDriver? I have automated test cases using Selenium with Java. Now I need to automate upload and download of a file using WebDriver. I had added webdriver-common-0.9.7376.jar. I like to use Internet Explorer. How can I do that?

I'm just declaring variable and using driver

```
private static WebDriver driver;
driver.findElement(By.id(upload)).sendKeys("file to be upload");
```

Is this correct?

Comment: The principle of getting the upload element and entering the filename is correct.  What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ques. 1: How to configure WebDriver?

Ans: There are 2 ways: 1) Adding "selenium-server-standalone-2.29.0.jar" only

OR,
2) Adding "selenium-java-2.29.0.jar" and all the jars located on "selenium-java-2.29.0\selenium-2.29.0\libs" folder

You can download "selenium-server-2.29.0.zip" and "selenium-java-2.29.0.zip" from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-server-2.29.0.zip and http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-java-2.29.0.zip respectively.
Extract them and you could get corresponding jar files to add.

Ques. 2: How to instantiate IE and how to upload file?

Ans: The java code as below:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.findElement(By.id("upload")).sendKeys("file to be upload");
```

If "File file = new File("C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe");" doesn't work download "IEDriverServer" and replace that line with below:

```
File file = new File("E:\\Ripon\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.29.1\\IEDriverServer.exe");
```

[Note: You can download "IEDriverServer" from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list ]

Comment: I think the link to the newest Selenium should be generic, the latest file will be changing over time and this answer will still be pointing to the (then outdated) file. Also, you don't need BOTH selenium-server and selenium-java. You need either the first, or the second one. Selenium-java is for WebDriver running locally, or for Selenium RC connecting to someone running the server. The selenium-server is the same plus for running Selenium RC locally (or as a server), Remote WebDriver and Selenium Grid. The "iexplore.exe" hint of yours should never work.

Comment: Slanec: I'm using eclipse for Java coding with WebDriver by using TestNG as framework. I have added "selenium-server-standalone-2.29.0.jar" and "selenium-java-2.29.0.jar": it's running well. When I removed "selenium-server-standalone-2.29.0.jar"  error was occurred in line - driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();  
com.gb.test.selenium.itinerarybuilder.ItineraryBuilderCreation
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setUp
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
 at com.gb.test.selenium.common.SeleniumTestCase.setUp(SeleniumTestCase.java:89)

Comment: It's missing the `com.google.common.base.Function` class which is a part of Google Guava. Google Guava is placed inside the `selenium-server-standalone` jar which is hardly a good practise, but okay. If you want it to compile this way, you need to add the dependencies which are bundled with `selenium-java` in the `lib` folder (included in the zip file, next to the jar). Or just use Maven or some similar dependency manager :).

Comment: hi, I don't wanna use Maven. I have added only "selenium-java-2.29.0.jar". In this case to cover com.google.common.base.Function which jar to be added?

Comment: All the jars that are in the `selenium-java-2.29.0.zip` in the `lib` folder. Those are the libraries needed by Selenium. If you don't want to manage those dependencies by hand, you could just use the `server-standalone` (without `selenium-java`) which bundles all those dependencies into it. The pros: It's easy to add and it can do more (Selenium RC, Grid etc.). The cons: The result is bigger than `selenium-java` and if you ever add any dependencies into your project, there is a risk of colllision of the two libraries (also known as [Jar Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_hell#JAR_hell)).

Comment: What's the difference between "selenium-server-2.29.0.jar" and "selenium-server-standalone-2.29.0.jar" ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add all jar after downloading selenium-java 2.25 0r any version. First add all jar then all all lib folder jar.

- selenium-java-2.25.0.jar
- selenium-java-2.25.0-srcs.jar and then all lib jar (Don't forget to add all lib folder jar)

Comment: Yes, it worked. some tutorials only ask us to add 'selenium-java-2.xx.x' jar to the build path, but the jars in the 'lib' folders are also necessary. I was struggling to findout the issue, and finally found the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Without  instantiate driver for your browser, it won't open a browser window to do the upload/download operation. If you're using IE you've to write `driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the old and outdated `webdriver-common` package, you probably need the newest `selenium-java` from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list.

If you'll ever also need running Selenium RC locally, or Remote WebDriver ot Selenium Grid, you'll need the `selenium-server` package there (if you don't yet know what these are, just take `selenium-java`).

In both cases, for running `InternetExplorerDriver`, you'll also need the `IEDriverServer` from the page mentioned above. It's up to you whether to use the 32 or 64 bit version.

---

You can find an example of setting it up [here in the documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example). If you dig around a bit, you'll find many more useful information in that documentation.

For example, for Internet explorer, you'll do:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

// your testing code

driver.quit();
```

---

Your method of uploading a file is correct.

And as of now (Selenium v2.29.0), you can't download files via any WebDriver. If you really want to do so, you'll have to [find another way](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=webdriver+download+file).

Comment: Selenium Server 2.29.0 is available now

Comment: @RiponAlWasim And you still can't download any files with it.

Comment: Yes, v2.26.0 also works. It was just my information about the latest version, nothing else